# prevenDefault Dont work

Tags: jquery, html, forms

```
<form action='process.php' method="post" id="contact-form">
     <label><span class="text-form">Nombre:</span>
            <input name="nombre" type="text" required />
        </label>
        <label><span class="text-form">Apellido:</span>
            <input name="apellido" type="text" required />
        </label>
        <div class="buttons">
            <div id="loader"> <a class="button" href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('contact-form').submit()">Enviar</a>
 <a class="button" href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('contact-form').reset()">Limpiar</a>

</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('#contact-form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
            var form = $(this);
            var post_url = form.attr('action');
            var post_data = form.serialize();
            $('#loader', form).html('<img src="images/loader.gif" /> Please Wait...');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: post_url,
                data: post_data,
                success: function (msg) {
                    $(form).fadeOut(500, function () {
                        form.html(msg).fadeIn();
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Im trying to just procces the submitting without loading the page.  But the prevent default is not working,

please any suggestion will be kind

Comment: why you think it is not working  ? give more deatils

Comment: whether the `form` elements exists on dom ready

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: Open the console and check for errors

Comment: are you sure it's not the return false whose block the ajax execution?

Comment: And why do you use anchors to submit the form, and not a submit button

Comment: you have nested dom ready handlers... you can remove one of them

Comment: calling `document.getElementById('contact-form').submit()` does not trigger the submit event so your submit handler will not get called

Comment: @adeneo you nailed it

Comment: I don't why it is getting downvoted...

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/S4ysk/3/ instead of using submit handler use click event handler for the submit link... also move the return statement to the bottom of the method

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Yup, using an anchor that way won't trigger the jQuery event handler.

Comment: For some reason I change the jqeury load to the top (it was in the footer) and It worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery anyway, why not invoke the submit event the same way?  Remove the inline `onclick` stuff, give the anchors some ids, and do something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#submitLink').click(function () {
        $('#contact-form').submit();
    });

    $('#resetLink').click(function () {
        $('#contact-form').reset();
    });
});
```

The anchors would just need those ids:

```
<a class="button" id="submitLink" href="#">Enviar</a>
<a class="button" id="resetLink" href="#">Limpiar</a>
```

**A few other things to note:**

- You're calling `return` *right away* in your handler, so none of that other code is going to run.  You probably want to return *at the end* of the function.
- Using anchors like this is very non-standard and may lead to further problems.  A good indication of this is "`href="#"`" which is kind of an anti-pattern in HTML.  I recommend using buttons for this functionality.  Anchors are meant for linking two documents together (or two locations in a document), not for invoking form functionality.

Comment: you are missing the id selector `#`

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, calling `document.getElementById('contact-form').submit()` doesn't trigger the `submit()` event. Since you're using jQuery, you can fix this by changing your 'Enviar' link to:

```
<a class="button" href="#" onClick="$('#contact-form').submit()">Enviar</a>
```

Once you've done that, remove the `return false;` located right after your `e.preventDefault()` line. It's causing the function to exit, preventing any code after it from running.